# How to fix Windows 7 jumpy display?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card

I have a PC that I built myself, based on a Gigabyte GA-MA78GPM-DS2H motherboard with integrated ATI 3200 graphics. It worked perfectly with the Beta version of Windows 7. I've finally gotten around to installing the final release of Windows 7, and now I've got a problem - screen updates aren't painting properly. Icons disappear, windows shift around and shrink, and the system is basically unusable.

I've tried updating the driver, but Windows says I have the latest driver. I also tried to download a driver from the Gigabyte site, but it didn't make a difference.

Any ideas?

Edit: I tried reinstalling Windows, but it made no difference. I don't have a problem before I log in, and it goes away if I delete the ATI driver. Unfortunately I need the ATI driver to get the resolution and speed I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the Visual Effects settings (right-click My Computer > Properties > Advanced > Visual Effects) to Adjust for best performance and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't quite know where to find those settings. I can't try it right now, but I'll report back later.

Comment: I can't find My Computer on Windows 7, but typing Visual Effects in the search box took me right to it. The crucial setting was "Enable desktop composition" - when I turned that off, all was right again.

Comment: For future reference, My Computer (or is it just Computer in 7?) is on the Start Menu by default in Vista/7.

Answer (score 1):

did you upgrade or a new install?
try deinstall of all ATI driver components and reinstall after a reboot. maybe you have to use a registry cleaner in between if the first attempt wasn't successful.
In worst case U'd have to clean install doing a full format of the filesystem instead of a quickformat.
I have seen such systems running perfectly on Win7.

Comment: I've tried a complete reinstall of Windows, but it didn't help. It was just a quickformat though, I have 2 partitions and I have stuff I want to keep on the second partition.